# CSS Crossbrowser web design

Tags: html, css

Where can I find a list CSS properties to support all browsers

For example:
I can make the background color of a *div* by using the following properties:

```
div
{
     background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
     filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#70FFFFFF',EndColorStr='#70FFFFFF'); /*IE*/
}
```

Finding this variations is hard do you know where can I find them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://caniuse.com has excellent compatibility tables covering all of the major browsers for html5,css3 etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good list if I understand your question correctly [CanIuse](http://caniuse.com/)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.browsersupport.net/

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/

Answer (score 0):

I'd add to Caniuse:

- [Mozilla Developer Network (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/) that tries to add other browsers problems, fix, way of doing things, etc (not complete, but it's a wiki and a work in progress these days).
- [CSS contents and browser compatibility](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) from PPK, Quirksmode
- [Sitepoint references](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css) (CSS, HTML and JS) (it begins to be a bit old in 2012 ... even if launched in 2010!)

Answer (score 0):

Surprised that no one mention the excellence [CSS Please](http://css3please.com). It is an interactive tool with live preview so you can just try things out and copy + paste. Your exact example can be found there.